# Set defaults for all Symfony Form Types

Tags: symfony, default, symfony-forms

Is it possible to set a default for all Symfony FormTypes?

We are currently working on an API Backend based on Symfony (3.3). In the Frontend we have our entities as objects looking like: `{"id": 1, "username": "foo" ..... }`

If we want to update the entity, we JSON.stringfy the object and send it to the server.

But if we bind the request to our entities via `$form->submit($request)` 
we get an error (*"This form should not contain extra fields."*) because we don't have (and don't want to use!) "id" in out FormTypes.

So we have to set `allow_extra_fields` to `true` in every single FormType

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(['allow_extra_fields' => true]);
}
```

Is there a way to configure this as a default for all FormTypes (without extending an custom FormType or something like this)?

Comment: How are you defining the id property in your entity? (In its annotation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a form type extension to change this default value to `true` for all form types.

> Form type extensions are incredibly powerful: they allow you to modify any existing form field types across the entire system.

```
class MyFormTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{    
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {  
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'allow_extra_fields' => true,
        ));
    }

    public static function getExtendedTypes(): iterable
    {
        return [FormType::class];
    }
}
```

See more about how to register type extensions in [Official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/create_form_type_extension.html#registering-your-form-type-extension-as-a-service).

**Note:** The `allow_extra_fields` option is defined in `FormTypeValidatorExtension` , so make sure your custom type extension is registered after it to override the default value, otherwise use the `priority` tag attribute to ensure it.

Comment: Since Symfony v6.* you may have it `return ['Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType'];` (return an array)